# Posting multiple forms on MVC Razor View with a Single View Model

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a razor view that will contain 5 forms. (A, B, C, D, E). Each of these forms has their own ViewModel (AViewModel, BViewModel, CViewModel, DViewModel, EViewModel).

I created a parent ProductViewModel that the page will use as its only ViewModel. Within this ViewModel will be all of the other ViewModels for each form on the page (listed above).

**Here is what the ProductViewModel's properties look like:**

```
public AViewModel { get; set; }
public BViewModel { get; set; }
public CViewModel { get; set; }
public DViewModel { get; set; }
public EViewModel { get; set; }
```

**My razor view looks like the following:**

```
@model MVCApp.ViewModels.ProductViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Product Detail";
}

<h2>Product Detail</h2>

<form asp-controller="A" asp-action="Save" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Form A</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AViewModel.Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="AViewModel.Name" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="AViewModel.Name" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AViewModel.StartDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="AViewModel.StartDate" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="AViewModel.StartDate" class="text-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AViewModel.EndDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="AViewModel.EndDate" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

When the Save button is clicked I end up in the Save (POST) Action Method of the A Controller just as I would expect:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Save(AViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

However, I noticed all of the properties of the viewModel param are empty.

Does this mean I really have to pass the ProductViewModel object as my ViewModel to the Save Action Method for all 5 of these forms where only the ViewModel in scope will be populated and everything else will be null? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest make each form a partial view and pass in only the sub model needed from the parent model

```
 @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("AViewPartial", Model.AViewModel); }
```

then your inputs in the partial can be changed from

```
<input asp-for="AViewModel.Name" class="form-control"/>
```

to

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control"/>
```

which should make it bind correctly by the modelbinder so it gets passed into your action

Comment: Partial Views is exactly what I need here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter to the POST method needs to be `ProductViewModel`.

The reason for this is because of the way the properties are named in your HTML:

```
<input asp-for="AViewModel.Name" class="form-control"/>
```

The model binder takes your serialized form, and sees that you're sending the POST method a value for a property named `AViewModel.Name`. When your parameter is of type `AViewModel`, it doesn't find anything, because it's looking for the *child property* of your parameter type with a name of `AViewModel`, and then assigning *that* object's `Name` property to the value of the input.

If you don't want to make the parameter of each of your POST methods `ProductViewModel`, then you have one leading alternative: Create Partial Views for your five different forms, and pass in the individual properties from your `ProductViewModel` as your model for the partial view. This will then eliminate the `AViewModel` property prefix from your `asp-for` attribute.